# Best way to remesh a lowpoly and a highpoly object?

Tags: workflow

i started blender a week ago, i did the donut tutorial and a chracter tutorial from keelanjon on youtube. i now can do some stuff even without tutorials...

few days ago i did my first toy figure without a real tutorial.. i just started modeling and if i didnt knew something or had a quesiton, i just went ahead and googled for it. i basically could answer all of my questions via google, still hard lol but i find my way around somehow... but some stuff i still dont really unterstand and cant really find a real answer...

1 - one day i want to do vinyl figrues like this dude here (hes using zbrush but i think all should be possible in blender too) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aki7NqTxkUc
im trying to get this kind of look ...

2 - i do stuff with multiple objects, for example i use spheres inside the head as a extra object.. i think this doesnt matter if i render the stuff or use for animation. but if i want to print  them the whole model needs to be one mesh right?
i tried to remesh (inside sculptingmode) the low poly objects with the high poly sculpted stuff and i always get weird polygons sticking out on the connections...can this be printed like this? whats the best way to combine them?

heres a pic of what my mesh looks like... u cant see the connections...
[image: wireframe]

3also i saw some parts have way to many polys for such simple shape are there any tutorials on how to stay low poly? idk if i use bevel and subdivsion modifier i always get a ton of polys.. is this normal?

also here is a picture of the render
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to 3D print, you need one mesh per object. So if you add eyes for example they need to be part of the head, unless you want to print them apart as different objects of course. To merge the eyes with the face, it's probably not a good idea to do it in *Sculpt* mode with the *Remesh* tool because it will probably deform your object a way you may not want, so instead use *Boolean* modifier, or simply extrude and modifiy the existing topology.

The best, particularly for the low-poly style you show, is to model a mesh that is as low-poly as possible, then give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to make it rounder, and at the end, when you're glad, duplicate the object, keep a copy with the modifier(s) non applied and apply the modifier(s) of the other copy.